# Determine if set is closed,open, bounded or compact

Tags: calculus, geometric-topology

$S= \{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}:  x^2  + y^2 = \frac{1}{n^2}, n \in \mathbb{N}$

Help me determine wether the set is closed,open, bounded or compact.

Determining if the set is bounded is trivial, but I am having some trouble determining if the set is closed, open or any of them. I'm pretty sure that the point $(0,0)$ can cause some troubles.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can write $S_n = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1/n^2\}$ and then $S = \bigcup_{n \geq 1} S_n$. This might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $S$ is not closed as the origin is a limit point of $S$ that doesn't belong to $S$.

$S$ is not open as you can't find an open ball centered on $(1,0) \in S$ that is included in $S$.